# Bootstrap columns not responsive in webpage

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am currently trying to have my display look like this where my top portion has 3 images equally distanced and at the bottom there are 2 images like below
[image]

I tried using Bootstrap by having the top 3 images as `<div className="col-md-4">` and the bottom 2 with `<div className="col-md-6">` but currently my layout looks like this when I make my screen size smaller.

[image]

This is my current code:

```
<div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-4">
            <div className="container5">
              <img
                style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
                src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png"
              />
              <div className="overlay">
                <div
                  style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    flexDirection: "row",
                    marginTop: "10px",
                    marginBottom: "-10px",
                  }}
                >
                  <div style={{ flexDirection: "column" }}>
                    <div
                      style={{
                        color: "white",
                        marginTop: "20px",
                        paddingLeft: "10px",
                        marginBottom: "-20px",
                      }}
                    >
                      Random Name
                    </div>
                    <div
                      style={{
                        fontSize: "14px",
                        color: "yellow",
                        paddingLeft: "10px",
                        marginTop: "13px",
                      }}
                    >
                      Software Engineer
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div
                    style={{
                      float: "right",
                      width: "50%",
                      direction: "rtl",
                      paddingTop: "25px",
                    }}
                  >
                    <img
                      style={{
                        height: "20px",
                        width: "20px",
                        backgroundColor: "white",
                      }}
                      src="linkedin.svg"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-4">
            <div className="container5">
              <img
                style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
                src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png"
              />
              <div className="overlay">
                <div
                  style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    flexDirection: "row",
                    marginTop: "10px",
                    marginBottom: "-10px",
                  }}
                >
                  <div style={{ flexDirection: "column" }}>
                    <div
                      style={{
                        color: "white",
                        marginTop: "20px",
                        paddingLeft: "10px",
                        marginBottom: "-20px",
                      }}
                    >
                      Random Name
                    </div>
                    <div
                      style={{
                        fontSize: "14px",
                        color: "yellow",
                        paddingLeft: "10px",
                        marginTop: "13px",
                      }}
                    >
                      Software Engineer
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div
                    style={{
                      float: "right",
                      width: "50%",
                      direction: "rtl",
                      paddingTop: "25px",
                    }}
                  >
                    <img
                      style={{
                        height: "20px",
                        width: "20px",
                        backgroundColor: "white",
                      }}
                      src="linkedin.svg"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-4">
            <div className="container5">
              <img
                style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
                src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png"
              />
              <div className="overlay">
                <div
                  style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    flexDirection: "row",
                    marginTop: "10px",
                    marginBottom: "-10px",
                  }}
                >
                  <div style={{ flexDirection: "column" }}>
                    <div
                      style={{
                        color: "white",
                        marginTop: "20px",
                        paddingLeft: "10px",
                        marginBottom: "-20px",
                      }}
                    >
                      Random Name
                    </div>
                    <div
                      style={{
                        fontSize: "14px",
                        color: "yellow",
                        paddingLeft: "10px",
                        marginTop: "13px",
                      }}
                    >
                      Software Engineer
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div
                    style={{
                      float: "right",
                      width: "50%",
                      direction: "rtl",
                      paddingTop: "25px",
                    }}
                  >
                    <img
                      style={{
                        height: "20px",
                        width: "20px",
                        backgroundColor: "white",
                      }}
                      src="linkedin.svg"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="col-md-6">
            <div className="container5">
              <img
                style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
                src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png"
              />
              <div className="overlay">
                <div
                  style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    flexDirection: "row",
                    marginTop: "10px",
                    marginBottom: "-10px",
                  }}
                >
                  <div style={{ flexDirection: "column" }}>
                    <div
                      style={{
                        color: "white",
                        marginTop: "20px",
                        paddingLeft: "10px",
                        marginBottom: "-20px",
                      }}
                    >
                      Random Name
                    </div>
                    <div
                      style={{
                        fontSize: "14px",
                        color: "yellow",
                        paddingLeft: "10px",
                        marginTop: "13px",
                      }}
                    >
                      Software Engineer
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div
                    style={{
                      float: "right",
                      width: "50%",
                      direction: "rtl",
                      paddingTop: "25px",
                    }}
                  >
                    <img
                      style={{
                        height: "20px",
                        width: "20px",
                        backgroundColor: "white",
                      }}
                      src="linkedin.svg"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="col-md-6">
            <div className="container5">
              <img
                style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
                src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png"
              />
              <div className="overlay">
                <div
                  style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    flexDirection: "row",
                    marginTop: "10px",
                    marginBottom: "-10px",
                  }}
                >
                  <div style={{ flexDirection: "column" }}>
                    <div
                      style={{
                        color: "white",
                        marginTop: "20px",
                        paddingLeft: "10px",
                        marginBottom: "-20px",
                      }}
                    >
                      Random Name
                    </div>
                    <div
                      style={{
                        fontSize: "14px",
                        color: "yellow",
                        paddingLeft: "10px",
                        marginTop: "13px",
                      }}
                    >
                      Software Engineer
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div
                    style={{
                      float: "right",
                      width: "50%",
                      direction: "rtl",
                      paddingTop: "25px",
                    }}
                  >
                    <img
                      style={{
                        height: "20px",
                        width: "20px",
                        backgroundColor: "white",
                      }}
                      src="linkedin.svg"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

and my current CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.container5 {
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: coral;
}

.overlay {
  clip-path: polygon(0 36%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1rem;
  bottom: -10%;
  background-color: #0e2043;
  transition: bottom 250ms ease;
}

.container5:hover .overlay {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: In smaller screen you want the cards to stack on top of each other right?

Comment: @RifkyNiyas Yea so as the layout gets smaller, the one card that has no more space left will go below. Also in my current screen, the row where I have put col-md-6, the cards are not centered and aligned to the left for some reason

Comment: Please add whole html code

Comment: @Danial Here is a Sandbox of the code for reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-dream-dc3uc?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Can You please share this code CodePen or JSFaddle so we can check it live. Thank you

Comment: @ShakibDShy I just did in the comment above

Comment: Okay. I understand your problem. Just a minute please I give you a solution.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Try Something Like This**

Please do not use fixed size when you want your layout be responsive. In `container5` css class you used `width: 300px`;.

*Here is your Live link* [Click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-violet-6cs64?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Over here as you can see, the bottom content I wanted hidden is now messed up. Also the image sizes my initial image is too big that it covers the entire height of the screen and I want it to be a particular size. So how can I decrease the current size of my image. Decreasing the height manually messes up the image

Comment: Can you please check it now. [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-violet-6cs64?file=/src/App.tsx) and the height you can control it with `@media query`

Answer (score 1):

1. You must not use fixed size when you want your layout be responsive. In `container5`  css class you used `width: 300px;`. This produce overlay problems.
2. If you want to have same view in smaller views when viewport is desktop, you can use `col-sm-6` or something else. [more info](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/#grid-options). So you can do it like:

```
<div className="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4"></div>
```

3. For images you can use:

```
<img src="..." className="img-fluid" />
```

Comment: The thing is my initial image is too big that it covers the entire height of the screen and I want it to be a particular size. So how can I decrease the current size of my image

Comment: Do you have problem yet? @JJM50